# JCrop is not working in ZF2 with similar code that was working for another core PHP application

Tags: php, zend-framework2, jcrop

I have implemented JCrop in my projects before in core PHP but when am trying to implement the same code in ZF2, its not working and i have added all the scripts and styles properly and they all are loaded, even the image is getting loaded but there is no selection box available to crop the image.

Suggesting a better way to implement the same functionality is welcome but it would be great if someone can tell me the reason for this not working.

here is the view script photo.phtml:

```
<?php
    //adding javascripts specific to this page
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js'));
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/jquery.min.js'));
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/script.js'));
    //adding stylesheets specific to this page
    $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('/css/Imageform_style.css'));
    $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css'));
?>
    <section>
    <div id="form_div">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Photograph</strong></legend>
         <!--upload form--> 
        <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
             <!--hidden crop params--> 
            <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />
            Step1: Please select image file
            <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" accept="image/*" />
            <div class="error"></div> 
            <div class="step2"> 
                <p style="">Step2: Please select a crop region </p>
                <div><img id="preview"/></div>
                <div id="image_details" class="info" style="display: none">
                    <p><label for="filesize">File size</label> <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" ></p>
                    <p><label for="filetype">Type</label> <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" ></p>
                    <p><label for="filedim">Dimension</label> <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" ></p>
                    <p><label for="w">Width</label> <input type="text" id="w" name="w" ></p>
                    <p><label for="h">Height</label> <input type="text" id="h" name="h" ></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    </div>                            
</section>
```

script.js contains the functions required on this page.

```
// convert bytes into friendly format
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
    if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};

// check for selected crop region
function checkForm() {
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    //$('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press Upload').show();
    alert('Please select a crop region and then press Upload');
    return false;
};

// update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
function updateInfo(e) {
    $('#x1').val(e.x);
    $('#y1').val(e.y);
    $('#x2').val(e.x2);
    $('#y2').val(e.y2);
    $('#w').val(Math.round(e.w));
    $('#h').val(Math.round(e.h));
};

// clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
function clearInfo() {
    $('.info #w').val('');
    $('.info #h').val('');
};

function fileSelectHandler() {
//    $('#preview').src('');
    // get selected file
    var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

    // hide all errors
    $('.error').hide();

    // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
    var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/gif)$/i;
    if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
        return;
    }

    // check for file size
    if (oFile.size > 2048 * 1024) {
        $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller than 2 MB').show();
        return;
    }

    // preview element
    var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

    // prepare HTML5 FileReader
    var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.onload = function(e) {

        // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
        oImage.src = e.target.result;
        oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler

            // display step 2
            $('.step2').fadeIn(500);

            // display some basic image info
            var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
            $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
            $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
            $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);

            // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
            var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

            // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
            if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') 
                jcrop_api.destroy();

            // initialize Jcrop
            $('#preview').Jcrop({
                minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
/// write code for changing the aspect ratio for signature file
                aspectRatio : 0.75, // to keep aspect ratio 1:1, use 1
                bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                onChange: updateInfo,
                onSelect: updateInfo,
                onRelease: clearInfo
            }, function(){

                // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                var bounds = this.getBounds();
                boundx = bounds[0];
                boundy = bounds[1];

                // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                jcrop_api = this;
            });
        };
    };

    // read selected file as DataURL
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

And it was and still is working in my previous project.

EDIT:
Here is the generated HTML for this code in head

```
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" 

rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/css/Imageform_style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Project1v3_zend/public/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Project1v3_zend/public/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should be :

```
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/jquery.min.js'));
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js'));
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('js/script.js'));
```

With jQuery being the first script to be appended? Since JCrop needs jQuery dependency to be satisfied?

Is there no console output in browser?

What does the generated html header for these scripts look like?

Comment: i have added the generated HTML in the post, check my edit. btw, i already thought of what u r suggesting and when i implemented that, what happened was that previously when i select an image to load it was loading but after changing the order and putting jquery first it didnt even display the image anymore.

Comment: What about console errors in your browsers developer tools?

Comment: There was an error in console as expected that you pointed out about the order but my problem was solved after replacing the JCrop script file with the latest version as it turned out that some code in the script wasn't compatible with new browsers. Thanks for your help mate.